# BitmapFactory.decodeResource() does not get my image from drawable

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I want to get `image` in my `bitmap` like this :

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bug);
```

but this show me error on `R.drawable.bug` that `bug can not be resolve or is not a field` please tell where I'm doing things wrong.

Comment: is there any image with named as `bug` in drawable??

Comment: change the name of your image and check.. and also clean your project once

Comment: It might not get updated in R.java, just clean the project and check it

Comment: Check your imports you may Have imported Android.R.java instead of R.java, try it once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you have a `bug` graphic file present in the `drawable` folder?
Have you tried to clean your project in order for `R.drawable` to be correctly generated?

Comment: Yes I have & I have also cleaned my project a couple of times, but the error still remains there!

Comment: Can you reference other resources from `drawable` or is it specific to this one? Do you import the correct `R` class and not `android.R`?

Comment: Can you validate an answer to close this issue?

Comment: import android.R seems to always be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.bug);
Bitmap pisc = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
```

Comment: I am surprised, but this approach display bitmap (thanks) and also helps me to avoid OutOfMemory error (double thanks). I cant explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy Your Drawable in all the drawable folders in your project.
like this
**drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi**