# loading image by bitmapfactory.decoderesource

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to put an image called greenball.png into my canvas.this image is beeing saved in drawable-hdpi folder but this line of code can not recognize my image, i mean "R.drawable.greenball" isnt valid. whats wrong in here?

```
public class myBall extends View {

Bitmap gBall;

public myBall(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    gBall=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.greenball);

}
```

i found the same question on stackoverflow :[BitmapFactory.decodeResource() does not get my image from drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220767/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-does-not-get-my-image-from-drawable)
but non of the answers worked for me! I cant even import R.java! it shows error!

Comment: What is your mean:  `i mean "R.drawable.greenball" isnt valid.`. IDE recognize it or when debugging it you see some logcat?

Comment: this part of code shows error so i can not run my code to see what is shown in logcat :| it cant find my image...non of the images in drwable folder

Comment: silly mistake ... prb is with ur **R.java** or while importing it

Comment: @maven would you read the cmnts of the below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are importing wrong `R` reference . check your import and make sure that you are importing your project `R` file and do not `import android.R;`

Comment: as i said i cant even import it...it shows error.anyway how do you import that?! i might be out of my mind!

Comment: *.it shows error.anyway how do you import that*, Then why dont you start focusing on the errors?

Comment: @SoheilaZangeneh : as i get it right , R.drawable.greenball cannot be resolved so i said checking your class import section at the top of your class. if your R import, like import com.example.R; has error so you have an error in your xml files which will cause your R file didn't generate. but make sure that you've imported your Project R file and not android R file.

Comment: if your R import, like import com.example.R; has error so you have an error in your xml files, right.it has error but non my xml files  contain error.by the way, there is an xml file in my drawable folder where my image is copied.Could this cause the error?

Comment: @SoheilaZangeneh : search for an error on problem view in Eclipse (if you are using eclipse). one other problem might be that you've assigned a String reference which doesn't have a name. without seeing/knowing Problem i think nobody can help you with that.

Comment: as far as i know, you cannt run a project containing errors in eclipse so how can i find any error msges in logcat while i cannt run it.now i see your import example com.example.R doesn't have error.the funny part is that the same project works in my frnd's pc! i really need your help :(

Comment: @Soheila : yes i've edited my comment so you cannot see that in LogCat but if you try to run it , it raise an error on Problem view.anyway if your project is not very big and you can.send me through my email. i will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Maybe its a coincidence but try to fix your ball image's size. I locked it to 75x75 and the problem is fixed